# Use full acronym name in TOC

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, glossaries, acronyms

I am trying to use `\acf` of the glossaries package in a `\section` command.

In my TOC I always get displayed the id, not the content. The generated section in the document works fine.

I was trying to use `\protect` but it doesn't work for me.

Is there no possibility like with a glossary entry `\glsentryfirst`?

Here my mini example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[pdfdisplaydoctitle=true,%
                 pdfstartview={Fit},%
                 bookmarksopen,%
                 colorlinks=true,%
                 linkcolor=blue,%
                 urlcolor=red,%
                 citecolor=blue]%
                 {hyperref}

\usepackage[nonumberlist,%
            acronym,%
            shortcuts, %
            toc,
            numberedsection]
            {glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{pus}{PUS}{\protect\glsadd{glos:pus}\glshyperlink[Packet Utilisation Standard]{glos:pus}}
\newglossaryentry{glos:pus}{name=PUS,description={\acl{pus} \ldots}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section[\glsentrylong{pus}]{\acl{pus}}
text
\ac{pus}

\newpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you please include a minimal working example?

Comment: There is now a working "not-working" example. ;)

Comment: It's impossible to work with the example as `acronym.tex` and `glossaries.tex` are missing. Just extract from them the necessary bits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\glsentrylong` in the optional argument of the sectioning command.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[pdfdisplaydoctitle=true,%
                 pdfstartview={Fit},%
                 bookmarksopen,%
                 colorlinks=true,%
                 linkcolor=blue,%
                 urlcolor=red,%
                 citecolor=blue]%
                 {hyperref}

\usepackage[nonumberlist,%
            acronym,%
            shortcuts, %
            toc,
            numberedsection]
            {glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{pus}{PUS}{\protect\texorpdfstring{\protect\glsadd{glos:pus}\glshyperlink[Packet
Utilisation Standard]{glos:pus}}{Packet Utilisation Standard}}

\newglossaryentry{glos:pus}{name=PUS,description={\acl{pus} \ldots}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section[\glsentrylong{pus}]{\acl{pus}}
text
\ac{pus}

\newpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I found a problem with your solution, perhaps there is a way for get it working. :)

Comment: @CSchulz What's the problem?

Comment: I have updated my mini example the use of an acronym linking on a glossary entry.

Comment: @CSchulz I've updated my answer.

Comment: Great! Thanks it works. :) So many things I don't know about latex.